# Problems in applying 3NF on ERD

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, 3nf

Here is my ERD:

[image: ERD]

I have tried to normalize this ERD and below is what i have done so far:

```
Country(CountryID{PK}, CountryName)
City (CityID{PK}, CityName, CountryID{FK})
Manager (username{PK}, password, ManagerName)
Airport (AirportID{PK}, AirportName, ICAO, IATA, ManagerUserName{FK}, CityID{FK})
Airline (AirlineID{PK}, AirlineName, IATA, ICAO)
AirportAirlineOffice (AirlineID{FK}, AirportID{FK}, Officeno) both FK = PK
Airplane (AirplaneID{PK}, Model, Make, AirlineID{FK}, AirportID{FK})
```

I am trying to normalize up to 3rd normal form so basically i am trying to achieve functional dependency and remove transitional dependency.
I have some questions which are confusing me:

1. In Airplane table, Make and Model should lie as it is or should be transferred to a new table?
2. In Airport table, should i transfer ICAO and IATA, code identifiers, to a new table?
3. Same goes for IATA and ICAO in Airline table.
4. And considering 3NF, Does manager table requires any changes?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.There is no problem if you keep these (make, model) in this table (Airplane).

2 & 3.If you transfer those code identifiers you will have to use FK but if you don't it will not be a problem for 3NF.

4.You used ManagerID in Airport table but there is no column named ManagerID in Manager table. So there is two options - (1) You can use username as foreign key in Airport table or (2) In Manager table you can use ManagerID as primary key and username as unique key.

Comment: oops, a mistake on my part. I will correct the FK in Airport Table